# The asymptotic expansion of $x^x$ at $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

If we put $x^x$ in [Wlofram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5Ex), we get the following:
$$
x^x = 1 + x \log(x) + \frac12 x^2 \log^2(x) + \frac16 x^3 \log^3(x) + \frac1{24} x^4 \log^4(x) + \frac1{120} x^5 \log^5(x) + O(x^6)
$$
Is there a name of this form of expansion and is there a systematic way to find such expansions?

Comment: The WA link you give call it a [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series), although according to wikipedia, they don't allow logarithms.

Comment: $x^x = e^{x\log x}$ and from this you can do a lot.

Comment: In this case, it is a power series in $x \log x$.  For more complicated things, there are transseries ... http://www.math.ohio-state.edu/~edgar/preprints/trans_begin/

Comment: Yeah, WA answers this, and the validity of this expansion should be questioned, in particular it cannot hold on $x<0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that 
$$x^x=e^{x\log x}$$
Also by Taylor's Series,
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$$
So
$$\begin{align}
x^x&=e^{x\log x}\\
&=1+x\log x+\frac{(x\log x)^2}{2!}+\frac{(x\log x)^3}{3!}+\frac{(x\log x)^4}{4!}+\frac{(x\log x)^5}{5!}+\cdots\\
&=1+x\log x+\frac{1}{2}x^2\log^2 x+\frac{1}{6}x^3\log^3x+\frac{1}{24}x^4\log^4x+\frac{1}{120}x^5\log^5x+O(x^6)
\end{align}$$

Comment: This skirts crucial definition aspects, why?

Comment: By the way, if you insists on adding an $O(\ )$ term, $O(x^6)$ is wrong.