# Find Taylor series of: $x^x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Find the Taylor series*polynomial form* of:

> $$x^x$$
>
> My attempt:

I started calculating derivatives of $x^x$ for the series,
$$f(x)=x^x$$
$$f'(x)=x^x(\ln x+1)$$
$$f''(x)=x^{x-1}+x^x(\ln x+1)$$
$$f'''(x)=\cdots$$
$$\vdots$$
But i could get only till certain terms and got frustrated,

> Attempt no. 2:

$$f(x)=x^x$$
$$f(x)=e^{x\ln x}$$
$$f(x)=1+x\ln x+\frac{x^2\ln^2 x}{2!}+\cdots$$
$$f(x)=1+x({x-1}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}+\cdots)+\frac{x^2}{2}({x-1}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-2)^3}{3}+\cdots)^2+\cdots$$
Now let's try to get $x^n$'s coefficient,
$$C(x^0)=1$$
In the bracket multiplied to x,
$$1+x(x-1-x^2+2x-1+x^3-3x+3x-1+\cdots)+\cdots$$
Following the lead
$$1+x(g(x)-1-1-1-1\cdots)+\cdots$$
$$C(x^1)=-1-1-1-\cdots$$
So,
$$C(x^1)=-\infty\cdots?$$
How do we write this equation?

> Attempt 3:

$$f(x)=1+(x+1)\ln (x+1)+\frac{(x+1)^2}{2!}\ln^2(x+1)+\cdots$$
Now,
$$f(x)=1+(x+1)(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}\cdots)+\cdots$$
Now,
$$C(x^0)=1$$
Considering $(1+x)^2,(1+x)^3\cdots$ contribution to$C(x^1)$
$$C(x^1)=1+1+1+1+\cdots$$
$$C(x^1)=\infty\cdots ?$$
Still.....stuck

Comment: Hint: $$x^x = e^{x\log x}$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, around what point do you want to take the Taylor series?

Comment: $x=1$ , i know $x=0 $ is a stupid move.

Comment: Similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2436009/357924

Comment: But not the same, i took care to search for such questions on the site

Comment: A question: how do you calculate fricatives of a function? :)))

Comment: I got a very nice and useless McLaurin expansion
$$x^x=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(x \log x)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+x%5Ex+for+x%3D1).

Comment: Looks like we could find a pattern. See [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ReplaceAll%5BTable%5BD%5Bx%5Ex,%7Bx,n%7D%5D,%7Bn,1,8%7D%5D,x-%3E1%5D).

Comment: Why are you leaving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2428757/) in its current, terrible, shape?

Comment: @Did I'm not able to delete it, i have clicked the delete button probably a hundred times.

Comment: @neonpokharkar Well, it seems you finally unaccepted the wrong answer. Good.

Comment: @Raffaele That's not a McLaurin expansion. It's not a power series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** We can find an elaboration of the $n$-th derivative of $x^x$ in an example (p. 139) of *[Advanced Combinatorics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* by L. Comtet. The idea is based upon a clever Taylor series expansion. Using the  differential operator $D_x^j:=\frac{d^j}{dx^j}$ the following holds:

> The $n$-th derivative of $x^x$ is
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{D_x^n x^x=x^x\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(\ln(x))^i\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}b_{n-i,n-i-j}x^{-j}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   with $\color{blue}{b_{n,j}}$ the *Lehmer-Comtet* numbers.
>
> These numbers follow the recurrence relation
>   \begin{align*}
> b_{n+1,j}=(j-n)b_{n,j}+b_{n,j-1}+nb_{n-1,j-1}\qquad\qquad n,j\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>   and the first values, together with initial values are listed below.
>
> \begin{array}{c|cccccc}
> n\setminus k&1&2&3&4&5&6\\
> \hline
> 1&1\\
> 2&1&1\\
> 3&-1&3&1\\
> 4&2&-1&6&1\\
> 5&-6&0&5&10&1\\
> 6&24&4&-15&25&15&1\\
> \end{array}
>
> The values can be found in OEIS as *[A008296](http://oeis.org/A008296)*. They are called *Lehmer-Comtet* numbers and were stored in the archive by N.J.A.Sloane by referring precisely to the example we can see here.

**Example: $n=2$**

Let's look at a small example. Letting $n=2$ we obtain from (1) and the table with $b_{n,j}$:
\begin{align*}
D_x^2x^x&=x^x\sum_{i=0}^2\binom{2}{i}(\ln(x))^i\sum_{j=0}^{2-i}b_{2-i,2-i-j}x^{-j}\\
&=x^x\left(\binom{2}{0}\sum_{j=0}^2b_{2,2-j}x^{-j}+\binom{2}{1}\ln(x)\sum_{j=0}^1b_{1,1-j}x^{-j}\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.+\binom{2}{2}\left(\ln(x)\right)^2\sum_{j=0}^0b_{0,0-j}x^{-j}\right)\\
&=x^x\left(\left(b_{2,2}+b_{2,1}\frac{1}{x}+b_{2,0}\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+2\ln(x)\left(b_{1,1}+b_{1,0}\frac{1}{x}\right)
+(\ln(x))^2b_{0,0}\right)\\
&=x^x\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+2\ln(x)+\left(\ln(x)\right)^2\right)
\end{align*} 
in accordance with the result of Wolfram Alpha.

> **Note:** A detailed answer is provided in *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607520/how-should-i-calculate-the-nth-derivative-of-fx-xx/1961167#1961167)*.

Answer (score 0):

By the formula
\begin{equation}\label{x-poer-x-thm3-driv-repl}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\bigl(x^{tx}\bigr)
=n!x^{tx-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}t^kx^{k} \sum_{j=0}^{k} \Biggl[\sum_{q=0}^{n-k} \frac{s(q+j,j)}{(q+j)!} \binom{j}{n-k-q}\Biggr] \frac{(\ln x)^{k-j}}{(k-j)!},
\end{equation}
one can derive Taylor series of the function $x^x$ around any point $x_0>0$.

References

1. Jian Cao, Feng Qi, and Wei-Shih Du, *Closed-form formulas for the $n$th derivative of the power-exponential function $x^x$*, Symmetry **15** (2023), no. 2, Article 323, 13 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.3390/sym15020323.
2. https://mathoverflow.net/a/439188